# Having Trouble Sending Arguments To Mintty/Cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, cygwin, mintty

Simply put, I would like to have a shortcut on Windows which can open up a terminal window just like clicking the Cygwin shortcut normally does, but in a different location from the default.

The normal Cygwin shortcut is made up as follows:

`D:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

This opens up in Cygwin's home directory, for me `D:\cygwin\home\marc`.

But how would I modify this shortcut so that it opens up in `C:\Coding` folder?

I've tried many variations and I've looked at the man page, but I just can't seem to get it to work, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [mintty wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Starting_in_a_particular_directory), you can create a shortcut with the target directory in the *Start In* field and the following command in the *Destination* field: `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l` (change the path to `mintty` as needed).

Comment: Superb, worked like a charm :)